# Symfony 4 FOSRestBundle boolean always wrong

Tags: fosrestbundle, symfony4

When I want to update my database I use a REST service using the patch verb.

Example:
http://localhost:8000/users/1?validate=false

False is never savd but against true is save.

Is my FOSRestBundle wrongly configured?

Here is the configuration of my FOSRestBundle :
[Configuration FOSRestBundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMKVX.png)

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `'false'` is not `false`

Example :

```
<?php
var_dump('false' == false); // false

var_dump('false' == true); // true
```